# SQL Cursor to insert comma separated values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

I have the following table TTC_CHILD

```
child_id Field_Name Sequence
1        Test       E,B
2        alpha      C,A,X
```

I have another table

TTC_CHILD_EXTRACT

```
Field_id Field_Name Sequence
 1       Test1        E
 2       Test2        Y
 3       Test3        B
 4       Test7        E
 5       Test8        Z
 6       Test9        B
```

TTC_CHILD_EXTRACT would have just one sequence (not comma separated). I want to insert field_id in 3rd table ttc_field where field_name would be inserted using like operator (like 'Test%', like 'alpha%') and sequence should be using in operator (in 'E','B') i.e.

TTC_FIELD should have following data for the above sample rows

```
 S.No. Child_id Field_id
  1      1        1
  2      1        3
  3      1        4
  4      1        6
```

as Test exists in only sequence E and B. I have thought of using cursor

```
DECLARE
     CURSOR TTC_CHILD_CURSOR IS
    SELECT CHILD_ID, FIELD_NAME,SEQUENCE FROM TTC_CHILD;

BEGIN
  FOR child IN TTC_CHILD_CURSOR LOOP
// here I want to loop the ttc_child table one by one and get the field id     from ttc_child_extract and insert that in TTC_Field       



END LOOP;

COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: NO, don't insert `,` separated values in table ... if you don't want future pains

Comment: this is definitely a duplicate. search for split comma delimited string to rows.  also update which rdbms you are using don't select them all.

Comment: @Matt I am not able to find out any other question that meets my requirement.

Comment: @Rahul  The comma separated data is what I got, I can't change it as this is a 3rd party data.

Comment: @Sunny I know the solution and I told you exact search terms that will get you what you want as far as separating values. I didn't tag a specific article because you have several RDBMs tagged.  Tag just the one you want the solution for.  after splitting the strings then search for row_number and you can build your other id.  A cursor is not necessary and wont get you everything you want.  if sql-server or oracle recursive cte will be easy again do a search and make an attempt at a solution.

Comment: @Matt I will search out. I am a java developer and I am working on such kind of requirement for the first time. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select rownum as "S.No", c.child_id, e.field_id
from TTC_CHILD c
join TTC_CHILD_EXTRACT e
on c.sequence like e.sequence || ',%'
   or c.sequence like '%,' || e.sequence || ',%'
   or c.sequence like '%,' || e.sequence 
   or c.sequence like e.sequence
```

Note: this query will probably be slow, and there is hardly anything you can do to speed this query up due to lack of normalization (data stored as comma separated text).
The only reasonable method is to normalize your tables.